# Generating multiple pandas data frames within a loop, with variable variable names

Tags: python, pandas, loops, variables, concatenation

I am trying to generate multiple pandas data frames within a loop, I am having difficulty with the variable definitions though. The first iteration of `str(test[i-1])` returns `A`, so I assumed I could concatenate this string with another string to create a variable, the first variable should be defined as `A_data_columns=['Test1','Test2']` however this throws an error (which I half expected), I was just wondering if there is a way to do this properly, or perhaps a better way?

```
test=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    test.append(chr(ord('@')+i))
    str(test[i-1])+'_data_columns'=['Test1', 'Test2']
    str(test[i-1])+'_dataframe'=pd.DataFrame(columns=str(test[i-1])+'_data_columns')
    str(test[i-1])+'_dataframe'
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str(test[i-1])+'_data_columns'` is a string, and not a variable name. You cannot assign a value to the string, it makes no sense.

One way to solve this would be to use a dictionary. In this way you can map a string to an object, which is what you are trying to do.

```
test=[]
test_dict = dict()
for i in range(1,5):
    test.append(chr(ord('@')+i))
    test_dict[str(test[i-1])+'_data_columns'] = ['Test1', 'Test2']
    test_dict[str(test[i-1])+'_dataframe'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=str(test[i-1])+'_data_columns')
```

You can then access the values as follows:

```
print(test_dict['A_data_columns'])
# should print ['Test1', 'Test2']
```